# Creating partitions locks the table?

Tags: mariadb, partitioning

I have a couple of big tables (from 60M rows to 2Bi rows) to create some partitions on it, as they are used in the core of our platform we are trying to find out if when we start to create the partitions in the production environment the database will generate any kind of lock on those tables?

We are on MariaDB 10.0.24 and 10.1.34.

```sql
ALTER TABLE data_history PARTITION BY RANGE ( period ) (
    PARTITION past VALUES LESS THAN (201801),
    PARTITION p2018 VALUES LESS THAN (201901),
    PARTITION p2019 VALUES LESS THAN (202001),
    PARTITION p2020 VALUES LESS THAN (202101),
    PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
    );
```

`period` column is an integer field that goes with year+month (YYYYMM) format.

Comment: `LESS THAN (201912)` probably excludes December?

Comment: Yeah, just notice that the ranges are off. FIxed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding `PARTITIONing` to a table, the entire table is copied over.  Hence the lock.

When adding a `PARTITION` to an already-partitioned table, it depends on the actual command issued.  All (?) cases will LOCK, but the length of the lock varies.  Please provide the actual command.

Why partition?  Partitioning does not intrinsically lead to any performance improvements.  See this for discussion of the few cases where partitioning is beneficial:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: I need to implement an archive process on those tables as most of the data is old and does not need to be available to the application. So I basically need to DELETE around 40% of the data in those tables after I copy the data over to the archive.

Comment: @MaltMaster - The link I provided is aimed at such applications -- a time series, and using `DROP PARTITION` instead of the much slower `DELETE`.  `EXCHANGE PARTITION` could be used if you need to move the data that has been removed.

Comment: We got the idea from the link you posted. Just added the SQL partition code we plan to use in the original post. We are in the planning phase for it and evaluating the impact in our system during the partition creation.

Comment: @MaltMaster - The initial creation of partitions will be costly; subsequent maintenance (drop & reorganize) will have very little impact on access to the table.

Comment: Would add one partition at a time be less costly?

Comment: @MaltMaster - Notice that it is a `REORGANIZE future INTO future, 202012` and that should be done about the time you start to insert into 202012.  If you do it too soon, you have extra partition(s) for no good reason.  If you do it too late, then any rows in `future` will need to be copied.  But that is a bonus--it is protection against failing to do the reorg in a timely manner (the rows wont be lost).